# Coding an equation with description

Tags: math-mode, equations

I want to code this equation in LaTeX:

[image: equation]

I'd like to know how to code the equation and the description below it with a reference as well.

Comment: It would be useful to know what you have up to now.

Comment: I'm pretty new to latex. My main query is how to put the dash above an alphabet, the big dash for division and the description as written here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even though your question was thoroughly answered here's my solution, it differs only in not using a table but a list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\[ P_{xi}=\overline{U_{x}}+\sigma_{x}\frac{\sum^{Nu}_{k}D_{kx}\times 
    \left( \frac{S_{ki}-\overline{U_{k}}}{\sigma_{k}}\right)}{\sum^{Nu}_{k}D_{kx}} \]
Where:
\begin{itemize}[label=]
    \item $P_{xi}$: is the predicted rate for user $x$ on item $i$
    \item $S_{ki}$: is the rate of song $i$ given by user $k$
    \item $\overline{U_{x}}$: is the average rate of user $x$
    \item $\overline{U_{k}}$: is the average rate of user $k$
    \item $\sigma_{x}$: is the standard deviation of all the rates of user $x$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following result:
[image: Equation and description]

Comment: You can use `\item[$P_{xi}$]` to set the label as the symbol - this makes sure the items align

Answer (score 17):

Some more flair in managing the "where" clause, and formatting of the conditions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  P_{xi}=\overline{U}_x+\sigma_x
         \frac{\sum_k^{Nu}D_{kx}\times\left(\frac{S_{ki}-\overline{U}_k}{\sigma_k}\right)}
              {\sum_k^{Nu}D_{kx}},
\intertext{Where:}
  \begin{tabular}{>{$}r<{$}@{\ :\ }l}
    P_{xi} & is the predicted rate for user~$x$ on item~$i$ \\
    S_{ki} & is the rate of song~$i$ given by user~$k$ \\
    D_{kx} & the correlation between user~$x$ and user~$k$ \\
    \overline{U}_x & the average rate over user~$x$ \\
    \overline{U}_k & the average rate over user~$k$ \\
    \sigma_x & is the standard deviation of all the rates of user~$x$
  \end{tabular}\nonumber
\end{gather}

\end{document}​
```

Comment: Another option is to use `\shortinertext` from the `mathtools` package as that provides tighter vertical spacing.

Comment: I did not know you could set which columns were math mode in tabular. That's really cool.

Comment: @EricR: All thanks to the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) using the `>` and `<` "directive". :)

Answer (score 8):

You can add the line over the variables using `\overline`. The text below can be done e.g. using a `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
    P_{xi} = \overline{U_{x}} + \sigma_{x} \frac
    {\sum_k^{Nu} D_{kx} \times \left( \frac {(S_{ki}-\overline{U_k})}{\sigma_k} \right) }
    {\sum_k^{Nu} D_{kx}},
\end{gather}
Where:\\
\hspace*{3em}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    $P_{xi}$:& is the predicted rate for user $x$ on item $i$. \\
    $S_{ki}$:& is the rate of song $i$ given by user $k$. \\
    ... & ... \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

You can change the space between the columns in the tabular by adding `@{\hspace{<your space>}}` between the `r` and `l` column type specifier.

Comment: I wouldn't overline also the subscript.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I agree. I had it different at first myself. I tend to replicate requested things as closely as possible. Bad engineering habit ...

Answer (score 6):

If you want to create a numbered equation as in your example, put the math part in an *equation* environment and add a `\label` that can be used to reference the equation later (with `\ref{}`). The LaTeX code of your equation could look like this:

```
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:mylabel}
  P_{xi}=\overline{U}_x+\sigma_x
         \frac{\sum_k^{Nu}D_{kx}\times\left(\frac{S_{ki}-\overline{U}_k}{\sigma_k}\right)}
              {\sum_k^{Nu}D_{kx}},
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Of course, you can tweak it to your liking, e.g. put the sum limits above/below the sum  (append `\limits` to the `\sum` command) or use bigger sum symbols. You should have a look into one of the many LaTeX books available to familiarize yourself with the system.