# Description list for equation's terms

Tags: math-mode, equations, enumitem, description

I'm trying to create a custom description environment (using `enumitem`) so I can describe the terms of an equation. What I want is to define item labels that are defaulted to inline math mode, and also to horizontally align the list to the right hand side of the items described, as in this example (without the colons):

[image]

I'm aware of the solutions given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53470/coding-an-equation-with-description) (in fact, I pulled the image from that post), but I'm required to use `enumitem` (not using `tabular`, `array`, etc.) and the `enumitem` solution doesn't quite do what I want.

So, how can I define a custom description list like that? I've tried using the package's documentation, but haven't been able to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this do?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{myright}{\hss\llap{$#1$}}
\newlist{where}{description}{1}
\setlist[where]{labelwidth=2cm,labelsep=1em,
                        leftmargin=!,align=myright,font=\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\[ P_{xi}=\overline{U}_{x}+\sigma_{x}\frac{\sum^{Nu}_{k}D_{kx}\times
    \left( \frac{S_{ki}-\overline{U}_{k}}{\sigma_{k}}\right)}{\sum^{Nu}_{k}D_{kx}} \]
Where:
\begin{where}
    \item [P_{xi}] is the predicted rate for user $x$ on item $i$
    \item [S_{ki}] is the rate of song $i$ given by user $k$
    \item [\overline{U}_{x}] is the average rate of user $x$
    \item [\overline{U}_{k}] is the average rate of user $k$
    \item [\sigma_{x}] is the standard deviation of all the rates of user $x$
\end{where}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scrextend` and `paralist`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:mylabel}
P_{xi}=\overline{U}_x+\sigma_x\frac{\sum_k^{Nu}D_{kx}\times\left(\frac{S_{ki}-\overline{U}_k}{\sigma_k}\right)}{\sum_k^{Nu}D_{kx}},
\end{equation}

Where:

\begin{addmargin}[4em]{1em}
\begin{compactitem}
    \item [$P_{xi}$]: is the predicted rate for user $x$ on item $i$
    \item [$S_{ki}$]: is the rate of song $i$ given by user $k$
    \item [$\overline{U_{x}}$]: is the average rate of user $x$
    \item [$\overline{U_{k}}$]: is the average rate of user $k$
    \item [$\sigma_{x}$]: is the standard deviation of all the rates of user $x$
\end{compactitem}
\end{addmargin}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-change-the-margins-for-only-part-of-the-text) excelent answer about `indentation`.

[image]