# Center hyphen between words

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have to center '-' mark in each line and it should be in the same location of each line. How would I do that?

```
\begin{flushleft}        
    $I(b)$ - interrogating signal\\
    $h_n$ -forward ross     \\
    $h_f$ - reversequite      \\
    $h$ - product ofall and wox\\
    $F_h(t)$ - interrrr        \\
    $S_m(b)$ - $m^{th}$ reponse of x thererer       \\
    $b(t)$ - received signal\\        
    $\omega(x)$ - noise added omega read         
 \end{flushleft}
```

[image]

I have used `\tab{}` and `\align{}` but I don't get results what I want.

Answer (score 7):

Taking some inspiration from [Coding an equation with description](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53470/5764), you can use a `tabular` to align the content. The output will not be breakable across the page boundary though:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{>{$}r<{$}@{\ --\ }l}
  I(b) & interrogating signal \\
  h_n & forward ross \\
  h_f & reversequite \\
  h & product of all and wox \\
  F_h(t) & interrrr \\
  S_m(b) & m\textsuperscript{th} reponse of $x$ thererer \\
  b(t) & received signal \\
  \omega(x) & noise added $\omega$ read
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Alignment of the left column is `r`ight, but you can adjust that to suit your needs.

Comment: why not use `tabbing`?  it isn't that much different from `tabular`, and it has the advantage that it *can* break across pages.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that uses an `array` environment. It's not clear to me how you want the first column to the aligned: Flush-left or flush-right. If it's the latter, change the column type from `l` to `r`. (If the body of the `array` environment looks just like the body of the `tabular` environment does in Werner's answer, that's not a coincidence: the `array` and `tabular` environments have a great many things in common.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\begin{array}{l @{\ \mbox{--}\ } >{$}l<{$}}   % place third column in text mode    
I(b) & interrogating signal\\
h_n & forward ross \\
h_f & reversequite  \\
h & product ofall and wox\\
F_h(t) & interrrr\\
S_m(b) & m\textsuperscript{th} reponse of $x$ thererer \\
b(t) & received signal \\
\omega(x) & noise added omega read  \\     
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not look like a non-duplication of my `tabular` approach. :)

Comment: @Werner - I mostly posted this answer to illustrate how TeX and LaTeX frequently provide more than one method for solving a given typesetting issue. And, of course, I took care to mention your prior answer. :-)

Comment: Although it looks OK I'm not sure about abusing math mode `-` here: should be `\hbox{--}` between the columns

Comment: @JosephWright - I've changed the code to use `\mbox{--}`, i.e., an en-dash. :-)

Answer (score 3):

still another possibility, using `tabbing`.  this has the advantage that it
can break across pages, anywhere in the list.

it's necessary to determine which left-hand entry is longest, to set the
width of the left column for the `\kill` line, but that needs to be done only once,
and is easy to change if a new, wider entry is added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\hyline}[2]{%
  $#1$\> --\kern.5em #2 \\}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
$S_m(b)$ \ \= \kill
\hyline{I(b)}{interrogating signal}
\hyline{h_n}{forward ross}
\hyline{h_f}{reversequite}
\hyline{h}{product of all and wox}
\hyline{F_h(t)}{interrrr}
\hyline{S_m(b)}{m\textsuperscript{th} reponse of $x$ thererer}
\hyline{b(t)}{received signal}
\hyline{\omega(x)}{noise added $\omega$ read}
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

if a right-hand-side entry appear that is longer than the page width will allow,
the `#2` in the definition of `\hyline` (a shorter command name could be used,
of course), a `\parbox` of appropriate size could be applied, with its contents
set ragged right.  this would ensure that appropriate baselines are used within
a single entry, a benefit if you decide that a little extra space should be
applied between entries (presumably as an optional dimension inserted after the
`\\[...]` in the definition).

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility which is less flexible (you have to specify the width of the left column explicitely) but works without any `align*`, `array` or `tabular` environment (note that `tabular`s will not be broken across pages) and allows for additional lines of text or even paragraphs in between if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
    \makebox[3em][l]{$I(b)$} -- interrogating signal\\
    \makebox[3em][l]{$h_n$} -- forward ross     \\
    \makebox[3em][l]{$h_f$} -- reversequite      \\
    \makebox[3em][l]{$h$} -- product of all and wox

\medskip
\noindent Further formulae use the more advanced\\
    \makebox[3em][l]{$F_h(t)$} -- interrrr        \\
    \makebox[3em][l]{$S_m(b)$} -- m\textsuperscript{th} reponse of $x$ thererer       \\
    \makebox[3em][l]{$b(t)$} -- received signal\\        
    \makebox[3em][l]{$\omega(x)$} -- noise added $\omega$ read   
\end{document}
```

The `3em` denote the width of the area reserved for the formulae. `l` is the alignment of each formula within this box (`l`eft, `r`ight, `c`entered).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the common labeled items of the  ubiquitous `itemize` environment?.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\mitem#1{\item[$#1$\quad---\quad]}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{itemize}
\itemindent.4\linewidth
\mitem{I(b)}       interrogating signal
\mitem{h_n}        forward ross 
\mitem{h_f}        reversequite  
\mitem{h}          product ofall and wox
\mitem{F_h(t)}     interrrr   
\mitem{S_m(b)}     $m^{th}$ reponse of x thererer 
\mitem{b(t)}       received signal        
\mitem{\omega(x)}  noise added omega read         
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The right alignment of the label can be obtained using a `\makebox` as in David's answer, but enclosed by brackets:

`\def\mitem#1{\item[{\makebox[1cm][l]{$#1$}}\quad---\quad]}`