# how to keep float out of gather env

Tags: floats, grouping

I was making description under equation using gather method from this [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53470/coding-an-equation-with-description) page.

```
\begin{gather}\label{eq:1}
R=\rho \frac{l}{A},
\intertext{Where:}
  \begin{tabular}{>{$}r<{$}@{\ :\ }l}
    P_{xi} & is the predicted rate for user~$x$ on item~$i$ \\
    S_{ki} & is the rate of song~$i$ given by user~$k$ \\
    D_{kx} & the correlation between user~$x$ and user~$k$ \\
    \overline{U}_x & the average rate over user~$x$ \\
    \overline{U}_k & the average rate over user~$k$ \\
    \sigma_x & is the standard deviation of all the rates of user~$x$
  \end{tabular}\nonumber
\end{gather}
```

In result some float image appeared between equation and description. 
What is the way to keep some block together disallowing floats to be placed inside of them?

Comment: your example code is incomplete -- it doesn't include any floating material.  please provide a complete (small) example that reproduces the problem, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Put the tabular into the `\intertext`, too:

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{gather}\label{eq:1}
    R=\rho \frac{l}{A},
    \intertext{Where:
      \begin{tabular}[t]{>{$}r<{$}@{\ :\ }l}
        P_{xi} & is the predicted rate for user~$x$ on item~$i$ \\
        S_{ki} & is the rate of song~$i$ given by user~$k$ \\
        D_{kx} & the correlation between user~$x$ and user~$k$ \\
        \overline{U}_x & the average rate over user~$x$ \\
        \overline{U}_k & the average rate over user~$k$ \\
        \sigma_x & is the standard deviation of all the rates of user~$x$
    \end{tabular}}\nonumber
\end{gather}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

Comment: didn't help, I still have floating figure between equation and description.

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: works, but... I feel that it should work like this, that it should be (page)breakable. There can be pagebreak anywhere in whole block, but no float is acceptable inside of it. Your answer is enough, but I am still looking for some "ideal solution)

Comment: you can try as optional argument for the float `[!htb]`

Comment: one more thing - linebreaking is not working. If description is long it stays in one line.

Comment: sure, you used a default r column instead of a p{width} one. Or a `tabularx` with a X column

Comment: solved with `tabularx`. So as long as I use minipage there is no need to use `intertext` and `gather`?

Comment: yes, that is correct