# Definitions for equations

Tags: tables, equations

I am trying to add the definitions for my equation in my document. 
I know this has been asked before and I found a beautiful solution. But it is just not working for me.

This is what I found

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
    \usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
    \begin{document}
        \begin{gather}
      P_{xi}=\overline{U}_x+\sigma_x
             \frac{\sum_k^{Nu}D_{kx}\times\left(\frac{S_{ki}-\overline{U}_k}{\sigma_k}\right)}
                  {\sum_k^{Nu}D_{kx}},
    \intertext{Where:}
      \begin{tabular}{>{$}r<{$}@{\ :\ }l}
        P_{xi} & is the predicted rate for user~$x$ on item~$i$ \        S_{ki} & is the rate of song~$i$ given by user~$k$ \        D_{kx} & the correlation between user~$x$ and user~$k$ \        \overline{U}_x & the average rate over user~$x$ \        \overline{U}_k & the average rate over user~$k$ \        \sigma_x & is the standard deviation of all the rates of user~$x$
      \end{tabular}\nonumber
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

and this is what I tried to make of it:

```
\begin{gather}
    dN/d(d_{p}) = kd_{p}^{\delta},
\intertext{Where:}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}r<{$}@{\ :\ }l}
 dN  : number of particles per unit water volume in the size range d p  to  [d p +d(d p )] \                                       
 k   :  (= constant) depending on the particle concentration \
 \delta   :   (< 0) descriptor of the distributions' spectral slope.  
\end{tabular}\nonumber
\end{gather}
```

If I put the "&", latex tells me, that I don´t have enough columns. Also the "\" is not showing up in red. I think the problem lies in the {>{$}r<{$}@{\ :\ }l} part. But I don´t understand what is going on in this.

Help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  Also, whay are you using `tabular` in math mode - you could just use `array` instead.  Or, better still, ust move the `tabular` out of math mode.

Answer (score 5):

You have been bitten by the infamous `\\` bug of the site, see [Double backslashes disappear from code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/double-backslashes-disappear-from-code)

You copied the code from

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53483/4427

which was affected by the bug. Here is the fixed code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
      P_{xi}=\overline{U}_x+\sigma_x
             \frac{\sum_k^{Nu}D_{kx}\times\left(\frac{S_{ki}-\overline{U}_k}{\sigma_k}\right)}
                  {\sum_k^{Nu}D_{kx}},
    \intertext{Where:}
      \begin{tabular}{>{$}r<{$}@{\ :\ }l}
        P_{xi} & is the predicted rate for user~$x$ on item~$i$ \\
        S_{ki} & is the rate of song~$i$ given by user~$k$ \\
        D_{kx} & the correlation between user~$x$ and user~$k$ \\
        \overline{U}_x & the average rate over user~$x$ \\
        \overline{U}_k & the average rate over user~$k$ \\
        \sigma_x & is the standard deviation of all the rates of user~$x$
      \end{tabular}\nonumber
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The fixed code for your attempt should be

```
\begin{gather}
    dN/d(d_{p}) = kd_{p}^{\delta},
\intertext{Where:}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}r<{$}@{\ :\ }l}
 dN     & number of particles per unit water volume in the \\
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & size range $dp$  to  $[dp+d(dp)]$ \\
 k      & (constant) depending on the particle concentration \\
 \delta & ($<0$) descriptor of the distributions' spectral slope.
\end{tabular}\nonumber
\end{gather}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you so, so much!!!

Comment: IMHO, in this case it seems that `\shortintertext` might be better.

Comment: Do I need a package for \shortintertext. It shows up in red, when I try. Also, I tried to apply this version of the equation for another one and get the message "Missing $ inserted. \end{gather}". What does that mean? Plus, if I try this with a third equation, it has the definition centered.

Comment: @Miklagard You need `mathtools`

Comment: I use the package mathtools, but I still get the error message plus this one: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char − (U+2212)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \end{gather}.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way that might be useful:

[image]

Using the `[t]` option on `tabular` yields better spacing above the `tabular` as per campa's comment.  However, according to egreg there is a potential problem with this affecting paragraph spacing but I was unable to see this problem so have posted: [Unable to duplicate problem: Using `[t]` option on tabular affect paragraph spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/368400/4301).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\begin{document}
\[
    dN/d(d_{p}) = kd_{p}^{\delta},
\]
where:

\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}l}
 $dN$     &: number of particles per unit water volume in the size range $d p$  to  $[d p +d(d p )]$ \\                                       
 $k$      &: (= constant) depending on the particle concentration \\
 $\delta$ &: $(< 0)$  descriptor of the distributions' spectral slope. 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @campa: Good suggestion. Have updated answer.

Comment: This way the spacing becomes bad at the end. Try adding a paragraph.

Comment: @egreg sure? I see no difference with `[t]` or without. Though `[b]` gives better spacing at the end, that's surely true. Maybe is a couple of `\smallskip` (before and after) better?

Comment: @campa Very sure, even without trying it.

Comment: @egreg: I can't seem to reproduce the problem you mention. I tried a short paragraph with preceeded with and without a blank line and tried `lipsum[1]` for a longer paragraph. Is there a reference for that on TeX.SE? A quick search did not show anything obvious to me.

Comment: @PeterGrill Try with a line with all x’s after the tabular (and a blank line).

Comment: @egreg: I still get identical results. I will post a question so that there can be reference for this issue.

Comment: @PeterGrill No need to: between the tabular and the next paragraph, `\lineskip` glue is inserted, so there's no guarantee that the two baselines are set `\baselineskip` apart. Try setting `\lineskip=2cm` and you'll see what I mean. It's a very well known problem. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34971/ for a related problem (the nature is the same).

Comment: Already posted [Unable to duplicate problem: Using `[t]` option on tabular affect paragraph spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/368400/4301). But, with `\lineskip=2cm`, the only difference I see is that there is less spacing above the `tabular` with the `[t]` option. Is this specifc issue a `minipage` related one? I don't see it affecting the paragraph spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, based on `framed` and  a `description` environment (more satisfying, semantically). Also, I think the `d` for the differential and the `d` in `d_p` are a somewhat confusing notation, so I decided to have the differential ‘d’ upright, with a macro found on this site

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand*{\d}{\mathop{\kern0pt\mathrm{d}}\!{}}

\usepackage{enumitem, framed}
\newenvironment{myleftbar}{%
      \def\FrameCommand{{\hspace{0.8cm}\vrule width 0.5pt}\hspace{6pt}}%\
      \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-2\width \FrameRestore}\noindent\hspace{- 0.4em}}%
     {\endMakeFramed}
\newenvironment{eqdescription}{%
\myleftbar
\llap{\makebox[1.4cm][l]{where: }}\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep}\strut
\description[font=\normalfont, labelwidth=0.5cm, align=right, leftmargin=!, itemsep=0pt]
}
{%
\enddescription\vspace*{-\topsep}
\endmyleftbar}

\begin{document}
\[
    \d N/\d(d_{p}) = kd_{p}^{\delta},
\]

\begin{eqdescription}
\item[$\d N$:] number of particles per unit water volume\\ in the size range $d_p$ to $[d_p +\d(d_p )]$,
\item[$k$:] (= constant) depending on the particle concentration,
\item[$\delta$:]$(< 0)$ descriptor of the distributions' spectral slope.
\end{eqdescription}

\end{document}
```

[image]