# Unable to duplicate problem: Using `[t]` option on tabular affect paragraph spacing

Tags: tables, spacing, paragraphs

I am having trouble duplicating a problem that is mentioned in the comments in [Definitions for equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368275/4301) where it is mentioned that with the `[t]` option on `tabular`

> spacing becomes bad at the end

I did not originally have the `[t]` option in the solution, but a comment alterted me to the fact that one gets better spacing just before the `tabular` with the `[t]` option and that part seems to be confirmed by the example in the MWE (first tabular uses `[t]` and second does not).

### Questions:

- When is it recommended to *use* and *not use* the `[t]` option in `tabular`?
- Under what conditions is the spacing affected by the use of the `[t]` option and when is there no affect of paragraph spacing?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\[
    dN/d(d_{p}) = kd_{p}^{\delta},
\]
where:

\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}l}
 $dN$     &: number of particles per unit water volume in the size range $d p$  to  $[d p +d(d p )]$ \\                                       
 $k$      &: (= constant) depending on the particle concentration \\
 $\delta$ &: $(< 0)$  descriptor of the distributions' spectral slope. 
\end{tabular}

xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.

xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.

\[
    dN/d(d_{p}) = kd_{p}^{\delta},
\]
where:

\begin{tabular}{r@{}l}
 $dN$     &: number of particles per unit water volume in the size range $d p$  to  $[d p +d(d p )]$ \\                                       
 $k$      &: (= constant) depending on the particle concentration \\
 $\delta$ &: $(< 0)$  descriptor of the distributions' spectral slope. 
\end{tabular}

xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.

xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The best way to improve the spacing is to add a \strut at the end of "where:" and the start of "xxxxx".

Comment: note the space generated by a blank line before the `\[`  is worse in many ways (especially if you get a page break there)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I assume you are referring to the second use `\[ ... \]`. That is not the thrust of this question so did not pay attention to that. Perhaps I should change that then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spacing is *clearly* bad: the baseline distance between the bottom of the tabular and the next paragraph is different from the other baseline skips.

The problem becomes very evident if you set differently `\lineskip` (the glue that's inserted between to lines who happen to be “too near” to each other.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\[
    dN/d(d_{p}) = kd_{p}^{\delta},
\]
where:

\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}l}
 $dN$     &: number of particles per unit water volume in the size range $d p$  to  $[d p +d(d p )]$ \\                                       
 $k$      &: (= constant) depending on the particle concentration \\
 $\delta$ &: $(< 0)$  descriptor of the distributions' spectral slope. 
\end{tabular}

xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.

xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.

\lineskip=2cm

\[
    dN/d(d_{p}) = kd_{p}^{\delta},
\]
where:

\begin{tabular}{r@{}l}
 $dN$     &: number of particles per unit water volume in the size range $d p$  to  $[d p +d(d p )]$ \\                                       
 $k$      &: (= constant) depending on the particle concentration \\
 $\delta$ &: $(< 0)$  descriptor of the distributions' spectral slope. 
\end{tabular}

xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.

xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Every box has a top, bottom, and baseline.  LaTeX places the baselines `\baselineskip` apart, or adds `\lineskip` between a consecutive bottom and top if the glue inserted to preserve baselineskip spacing would be less than `\lineskiplimit` (in other words, whichever is larger).

The following shows the top, bottom and baseline for your example tabulars.  The third example uses `\strut`s to compensate for the lack of decenders and ascenders in the text.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fboxsep=0pt

\begin{document}
\[
    dN/d(d_{p}) = kd_{p}^{\delta},
\]
where:

\noindent\fbox{\rlap{\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}l}
 $dN$     &: number of particles per unit water volume in the size range $d p$  to  $[d p +d(d p )]$ \\                                       
 $k$      &: (= constant) depending on the particle concentration \\
 $\delta$ &: $(< 0)$  descriptor of the distributions' spectral slope. 
\end{tabular}}\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}}

xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.

xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.

\[
    dN/d(d_{p}) = kd_{p}^{\delta},
\]
where:

\noindent\fbox{\rlap{\begin{tabular}{r@{}l}
 $dN$     &: number of particles per unit water volume in the size range $d p$  to  $[d p +d(d p )]$ \\                                       
 $k$      &: (= constant) depending on the particle concentration \\
 $\delta$ &: $(< 0)$  descriptor of the distributions' spectral slope. 
\end{tabular}}\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}}

xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.

xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.

\[
    dN/d(d_{p}) = kd_{p}^{\delta},
\]
where:\strut

\noindent\begin{tabular}{r@{}l}
 $dN$     &: number of particles per unit water volume in the size range $d p$  to  $[d p +d(d p )]$ \\                                       
 $k$      &: (= constant) depending on the particle concentration \\
 $\delta$ &: $(< 0)$  descriptor of the distributions' spectral slope. 
\end{tabular}

\strut
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.

xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx.

\end{document}
```

Comment: could you change "(whichever is larger)" to "(if the glue inserted to preserve baselineskip spacing would be less than `\lineskiplimit`)